# How to parse a JSONP response and return a value using OpenLayers?

Tags: json, jsonp, openlayers, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I am using OpenLayers and geoserver to build an app. very new to everything and this is my first app. Now I am trying to use the WMS getFeatureInfo to fetch feature information and show in popups when users click on a feature. To get around the cross domain issue, I am now trying to get JSONP response. the response i got is:

```
parseResponse({"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"Fire_Boundary_Pro.1","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[414495.86280000024,6451439.778],[414501.3269999996,6451437.0124],[414572.5887000002,6451444.5907],[414614.8359000003,6451368.1611],[414679.86149999965,6451410.5882],[414793.0769999996,6451376.6343],[414905.6501000002,6451419.4576],[414983.7874999996,6451315.405],[414978.77660000045,6451203.6776],[415021.0197999999,6451127.2464],[415051.8420000002,6450994.8769],[415029.2346000001,6450855.0812],[414899.8300999999,6450693.4524],[414882.8183000004,6450595.5852],[414776.48950000014,6450517.9117],[414747.5351999998,6450426.9246],[414688.4584999997,6450384.5476],[414605.3772,6450369.8903],[414568.95940000005,6450460.3295],[414555.8437000001,6450606.8071],[414473.11259999964,6450550.2695],[414468.34250000026,6450410.6221],[414433.15529999975,6450354.4835],[414350.7204999998,6450263.0455],[414273.40699999966,6450269.3751],[414076.47389999963,6450365.4401],[414061.89190000016,6450388.7117],[414037.87590000033,6450380.4262],[413891.39940000046,6450430.6506],[413934.48699999973,6450516.7853],[413948.07650000043,6450636.9786],[413961.37650000025,6450791.4776],[414092.2400000002,6450861.1987],[414153.67080000043,6450897.9731],[414179.43510000035,6450913.3962],[414281.23610000033,6450965.7158],[414279.7922,6451137.244],[414352.3854,6451189.3169],[414395.91280000005,6451223.991],[414350.94269999955,6451360.8451],[414495.86280000024,6451439.778]]]]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"area":8.09003398112E-5,"Shape_Leng":4319.38797802,"Shape_Area":828429.079784}}]})
```

However I am not sure how to parse the JSONP response and obtain a property value. I am trying to use the OpenLayers.Format.JSON.read method (not sure if this is the right way to do it) but it returns an error that it is an undefined constructor.  Here is my code:

```
map.events.register('click', map, function (e) {
                document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";

                var params = {
                    REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
                    EXCEPTIONS: "text/javascript",
                    BBOX: map.getExtent().toBBOX(),
                    SERVICE: "WMS",
                    //use JSONP format
                    INFO_FORMAT: 'text/javascript',
                    QUERY_LAYERS: map.layers[0].params.LAYERS,
                    FEATURE_COUNT: 50,
                    Layers: 'Bushfire_Com_Study:Fire_Boundary_Pro',
                    WIDTH: map.size.w,
                    HEIGHT: map.size.h,
                    format: format,
                    styles: map.layers[0].params.STYLES,
                    srs: map.layers[0].params.SRS,

                // handle the wms 1.3 vs wms 1.1 madness
                if(map.layers[0].params.VERSION == "1.3.0") {
                    params.version = "1.3.0";
                    params.j = parseInt(e.xy.x);
                    params.i = parseInt(e.xy.y);
                } else {
                    params.version = "1.1.1";
                    params.x = parseInt(e.xy.x);
                    params.y = parseInt(e.xy.y);
                }

                // merge filters
                if(map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER != null) {
                    params.cql_filter = map.layers[0].params.CQL_FILTER;
                } 
                if(map.layers[0].params.FILTER != null) {
                    params.filter = map.layers[0].params.FILTER;
                }
                if(map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID) {
                    params.featureid = map.layers[0].params.FEATUREID;
                }

                OpenLayers.loadURL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Bushfire_Com_Study/wms", params, this, setHTML, setHTML);
                OpenLayers.Event.stop(e);
            });


        // sets the HTML provided into the nodelist element
        function setHTML(response){
            var json_format = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON();
            var object = json_format.read(response);
            document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = object.features[0].properties['area'];
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere else. Most important sources for a solution were
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol/Script-js.html
and 
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html#wms-vendor-parameters.

My code contained things similar to the following.

```js
// The Script protocol will insert the JSONP response in to the DOM.
var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
  url: someUrl,
  callback: someCallbackFunction,
});

// GeoServer specific settings for the JSONP request.
protocol.callbackKey = 'format_options';
protocol.callbackPrefix = 'callback:';

// WMS parameters like in the question
var params={
  REQUEST: "GetFeatureInfo",
  EXCEPTIONS: "text/javascript",
  INFO_FORMAT: 'text/javascript',
  //etc
};

// Send the request.
protocol.read({
  params: params
});

// Callback to handle the response.
function someCallbackFunction(response) {
  for(var feature in response.features) {
    // Do something with the returned features.
  }
}
```